# How do I create a many-to-many relationship with Entity Framework code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following error is displayed when trying to create a code first many-to-many relationship. Could someone tell me what is wrong, please? I've searched everywhere and can't see what is wrong with the code.

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.BookingPeople_dbo.People_PersonID' on table 'BookingPeople' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

migration:

```
        public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Bookings",
            c => new
                {
                    BookingID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    startDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    endDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Contact_PersonID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Type_BookingTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.BookingID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.Contact_PersonID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.BookingTypes", t => t.Type_BookingTypeID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Contact_PersonID)
            .Index(t => t.Type_BookingTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.People",
            c => new
                {
                    PersonID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PersonAge = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Type_PersonTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.PersonTypes", t => t.Type_PersonTypeID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Type_PersonTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.PersonTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    PersonTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Type = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.BookingTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    BookingTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Type = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.BookingTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    UserID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Username = c.String(maxLength: 30),
                    Password = c.String(unicode: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.BookingPeople",
            c => new
                {
                    BookingID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PersonID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.BookingID, t.PersonID })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Bookings", t => t.BookingID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.PersonID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.BookingID)
            .Index(t => t.PersonID);

    }
```

Fluent API code:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(e => e.Password)
            .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
            .HasMany(t => t.People)
            .WithMany(t => t.Bookings)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("BookingPeople");
                m.MapLeftKey("BookingID");
                m.MapRightKey("PersonID");
            });
    }
```

Booking class:

```
    public class Booking
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int BookingID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public BookingType Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Person Contact { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }

}
```

Person class:

```
    public class Person
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PersonAge { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public PersonType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

**Updated code**

migration:

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Bookings",
            c => new
                {
                    BookingID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    startDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    endDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    BookingType_BookingTypeID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.BookingID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.BookingID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.BookingTypes", t => t.BookingType_BookingTypeID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.BookingTypes", t => t.BookingID)
            .Index(t => t.BookingID)
            .Index(t => t.BookingType_BookingTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.People",
            c => new
                {
                    PersonID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PersonAge = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PersonType_PersonTypeID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.PersonTypes", t => t.PersonType_PersonTypeID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.PersonTypes", t => t.PersonID)
            .Index(t => t.PersonID)
            .Index(t => t.PersonType_PersonTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.PersonTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    PersonTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Type = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.BookingTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    BookingTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Type = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.BookingTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    UserID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Username = c.String(maxLength: 30),
                    Password = c.String(unicode: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.BookingPeople",
            c => new
                {
                    BookingID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PersonID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.BookingID, t.PersonID })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Bookings", t => t.BookingID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.PersonID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.BookingID)
            .Index(t => t.PersonID);

    }
```

Booking:

```
    public partial class Booking
{        
    public int BookingID { get; set; }


    public BookingType Type { get; set; }


    public Person Contact { get; set; }


    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }


    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }

}
```

Person:

```
    public partial class Person
{        
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public int PersonAge { get; set; }

    public PersonType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(e => e.Password)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        // Booking
        // -------

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.Contact)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.Type)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
        .HasMany(t => t.People)
        .WithMany(t => t.Bookings)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("BookingPeople");
            m.MapLeftKey("BookingID");
            m.MapRightKey("PersonID");
        });


        // Person
        // ------

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.Type)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


    }
```

**Updated code:**

Migration:

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Bookings",
            c => new
                {
                    BookingID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    startDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    endDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Contact_PersonID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    BookingType_BookingTypeID = c.Int(),
                    Type_BookingTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.BookingID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.Contact_PersonID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.BookingTypes", t => t.BookingType_BookingTypeID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.BookingTypes", t => t.Type_BookingTypeID)
            .Index(t => t.Contact_PersonID)
            .Index(t => t.BookingType_BookingTypeID)
            .Index(t => t.Type_BookingTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.People",
            c => new
                {
                    PersonID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    PersonAge = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PersonType_PersonTypeID = c.Int(),
                    Type_PersonTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.PersonTypes", t => t.PersonType_PersonTypeID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.PersonTypes", t => t.Type_PersonTypeID)
            .Index(t => t.PersonType_PersonTypeID)
            .Index(t => t.Type_PersonTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.PersonTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    PersonTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Type = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.BookingTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    BookingTypeID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Type = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.BookingTypeID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    UserID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Username = c.String(maxLength: 30),
                    Password = c.String(unicode: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.BookingPeople",
            c => new
                {
                    BookingID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PersonID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.BookingID, t.PersonID })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Bookings", t => t.BookingID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.PersonID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.BookingID)
            .Index(t => t.PersonID);

    }
```

Fluent API code:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(e => e.Password)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        // Booking
        // -------

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.Contact)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.Type)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
        .HasMany(t => t.People)
        .WithMany(t => t.Bookings)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("BookingPeople");
            m.MapLeftKey("BookingID");
            m.MapRightKey("PersonID");
        });


        // Person
        // ------

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.Type)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this maybe the problem

```
[Required]
public Person Contact { get; set; }
```

as the `Required` attribute means cascade delete is set to true by EF (eg when you delete a booking the Contact (Person) is deleted but that  person maybe referenced by another booking hence the error message

To fix remove the required attribute and specify the relationship in [FluentApi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

In your DbContext class

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
            .HasRequired(b => b.Contact)
            .WithOptional()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: I've added the code, but now Contact is not a part of the migration. I've uploaded the latest code to the post.

Comment: `.WithOptional()` should probably be `WithMany()`. @JamesPeters I think this answer is spot on. There should be a foreign key to `Person` in `Booking` now.

Comment: I've added WithMany() and there is now a foreign key to Person in Booking in the above migration, but there is now an extra foreign key and field for BookingType which doesn't exist.